# Using linspace in Julia 0.7

Tags: julia

I am confused about using linspace in Julia 0.7. Here is the what I entered in the REPL and the result:

```
julia> a = linspace(0.1,1.1,6)
┌ Warning: `linspace(start, stop, length::Integer)` is deprecated, use `range(start, stop=stop, length=length)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope
└ @ Core :0
0.1:0.2:1.1
```

My question is about the deprecated warning and the suggested use of range. The range statement doesn't do the same thing as the linspace command.

If you enter the a = linspace(0.1,1.1,6) and collect(a), you get the following:

```
julia> collect(a)
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.1
 0.3
 0.5
 0.7
 0.9
 1.1
```

If you enter  b = range(0.1,1.1,6) and collect(b), you get:

```
julia> collect(b)
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.1
 1.2
 2.3
 3.4
 4.5
 5.6
```

This is obviously not the same.

Why is linspace deprecated (perhaps a different question) and a non-equivalent range command suggested?

My actual question is: Is it safe to keep using linspace for the desired results it provides, and, if not, what should I be using instead?

Comment: In Julia 1.4, I've taken to simply adding the line `linspace(a,b,n) = collect(range(a,stop=b,length=n))` at the start of my code to restore the function. This keeps old code running without refactoring, and keeps the API close to numpy/matlab which improves portability and reduces development time when working across these languages.

Comment: @MRule Don't use `collect` here. It is redundant, and reduces performance. Use range objects as they are, without collecting them into heavyweight arrays. (In fact, in 99.99% of cases, don't use `collect` *anywhere*.)

Answer (score 18):

You should use `LinRange`, as documented [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/base/collections/#Base.LinRange).

> A range with len linearly spaced elements between its start and stop. The size of the spacing is controlled by len, which must be an Int.

```
julia> LinRange(1.5, 5.5, 9)
9-element LinRange{Float64}:
 1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,5.5
```

Edit 2021: As of version 1.7 you can use the `range` function for this:

```
jl> range(1.5, 5.5, 9)
1.5:0.5:5.5
```

For version 1.6 you have to write: `range(1.5, 5.5, length=9)`.

Comment: I'm confused by the downvotes. How is this not helpful?

Comment: I guess, it must be because it's not documented.

Comment: @SalchiPapa I think it is awkward to decrease DNFs reputation because Julia is in flux. Maybe we could try to balance this answer at zero? ;)

Comment: @Liso, I don't really mind reputation points myself, but there you go, back at 0 again. :) Still, an example (specially because is undocumented) to reproduce the same output with `LinRange`, would be nice. Linking to a discussion is helpful, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It is documented now: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/base/collections/#Base.LinRange

Answer (score 14):

Following the deprecations, it is now:

```
julia> range(0.1, stop = 1.1, length = 6) |> collect
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.1
 0.3
 0.5
 0.7
 0.9
 1.1
```

In your example, the second argument is a `step`, not the `stop`, notice this method is also deprecated, you have to use keyword arguments now:

```
julia> @which range(0.1, 1.1, 6)
range(start, step, length) in Base at deprecated.jl:53
```

Comment: As a remark, from Julia 1.1 on the stop keyword can be omitted, that is the second positional argument is interpreted as stop automatically.